# Error compiling typescript in docker for express app

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a typescript app in docker but I am running into some issues.

The error that I receive is `sh: 1: tsc: not found`, despite typescript being in the dev-dependencies. I ideally thought that given in my dockerfile I am running npm install, it would also install the devDependencies and bring in Typescript, but is that not true?

My `package.json` is :

```
{
  "name": "ts-express-starter-kit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Opinionated starter kit for typescript and express",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently -k -n \"TypeScript,Node\" -c \"yellow.bold,cyan.bold\" \"npm run watch-ts\" \"nodemon ./dist/index.js\"",
    "watch-ts": "tsc -w"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "express"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/config": "0.0.34",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.138",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.7.35",
    "@types/mysql": "^2.15.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.10",
    "config": "^3.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-enrouten": "^1.3.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "sequelize": "^5.18.4",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.1",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.5.4"
  }
}
```

My `Dockerfile` is :

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

And `docker-compose.yaml` is:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    container_name: tw-backend # How the container will appear when listing containers from the CLI
    build: .
    image: node:10 
    user: node 
    working_dir: "/app" 
    networks:
    - app
    ports:
    - "8080:8080" 
    volumes:
    - ./:/app docker 

networks:
  app:
```

Comment: can you try removing `    volumes:
    - ./:/app docker ` from compose.

Comment: The `image:` you have there is dangerous (it says the image you're building is the standard Node image) and might cause your image to not be built; I'd delete that line.  The `package.json` setup you show looks like something you'd run in live development and not something you'd run in Docker, though.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to the `.bin` directory of your (local) `node_modules` directory not being added to the environments `$PATH` variable as demonstrated below:

```
root@f932304632f2:/app# export
declare -x HOME="/root"
declare -x HOSTNAME="f932304632f2"
declare -x NODE_VERSION="10.17.0"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
declare -x PWD="/app"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x TERM="xterm"
declare -x YARN_VERSION="1.19.1"
```

Listing out `/app/node_modules/.bin` (as you can see, things *are* installed after all):

```
root@f932304632f2:/app# ls -la node_modules/.bin
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Dec  1 08:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 308 root root 12288 Dec  1 08:40 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    35 Dec  1 08:40 concurrently -> ../concurrently/bin/concurrently.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    37 Dec  1 08:40 css-beautify -> ../js-beautify/js/bin/css-beautify.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    32 Dec  1 08:40 editorconfig -> ../editorconfig/bin/editorconfig
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    38 Dec  1 08:40 html-beautify -> ../js-beautify/js/bin/html-beautify.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    15 Dec  1 08:40 is-ci -> ../is-ci/bin.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    36 Dec  1 08:40 js-beautify -> ../js-beautify/js/bin/js-beautify.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    19 Dec  1 08:40 json5 -> ../json5/lib/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 Dec  1 08:40 mime -> ../mime/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    20 Dec  1 08:40 mkdirp -> ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    25 Dec  1 08:40 nodemon -> ../nodemon/bin/nodemon.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    25 Dec  1 08:40 nodetouch -> ../touch/bin/nodetouch.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    19 Dec  1 08:40 nopt -> ../nopt/bin/nopt.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    12 Dec  1 08:40 rc -> ../rc/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    23 Dec  1 08:40 semver -> ../semver/bin/semver.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Dec  1 08:40 sequelize -> ../sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    30 Dec  1 08:40 sequelize-cli -> ../sequelize-cli/lib/sequelize
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    19 Dec  1 08:40 tree-kill -> ../tree-kill/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    22 Dec  1 08:40 ts-node -> ../ts-node/dist/bin.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    25 Dec  1 08:40 ts-script -> ../ts-node/dist/script.js
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    21 Dec  1 08:40 tsc -> ../typescript/bin/tsc
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    26 Dec  1 08:40 tsserver -> ../typescript/bin/tsserver
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    16 Dec  1 08:40 uuid -> ../uuid/bin/uuid
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    18 Dec  1 08:40 which -> ../which/bin/which
root@f932304632f2:/app#
```

You have a couple of options to handle this.. you (should) use `npx ..command..` (i.e.: `npx tsc -w`) and let node handle the resolution for you OR `npm install typescript -g` (not recommended) OR use `./node_modules/.bin/tsc -w` (okay, but not safe if you move things around). I'd opt for #1.